# Copying objects from one json array to another

Tags: c, json

I'm iterating through the array of json objects and putting specific elements into another.

```
 char *jsonString = getList(); // reads file and returns json string
 json_error_t err;
 json_t *jsonArr = json_loads(jsonString , 0 , &err);
 int index = 0;
 json_t *value = NULL;
 json_t *resultArr = malloc(sizeof(json_t) * 100);

 json_array_foreach(jsonArr , index , value)
 {  
     if(strcmp(json_string_value(json_object_get(value , "citizenship")) , key) == 0)
     {
         json_array_append_new(resultArr , value);
     } 
 }

 printf("Array size : %i\n" , (int)json_array_size(resultArr));

 char * result = json_dumps(resultArr , JSON_INDENT(2));
 json_decref(jsonArr);
 json_decref(resultArr);

 return result;
```

I am sure that I have 3 elements matching search and it is true judging by the number of if-statement entries, though printf() after the loop says that this newly created array is empty. Are there any obvious issues that you can point out? I'm using jansson library.

Comment: Any reason you use `json_array_append_new` vs. `json_array_append`? Also, check your return values to calls like malloc and append, making sure there aren't any errors.

Comment: Also, use `json_t *resultArr = json_array();`

Comment: Thank you very much, json_array() did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you need to create the `json_t` array using `json_array()`.

You can [see some good examples](https://github.com/akheron/jansson/blob/98be7da3e2cc256e16d3c9f76b3a0053a930eb2c/test/suites/api/test_array.c) by looking at the tests the Jansson author has on GitHub.